# Desativar botão Return do `UITextField`

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tem alguma maneira, sem gambiarras, de desativar o botão Return de um `UITextField`?

Tenho uma tela com dois `UITextField`, um de texto e um numérico, preciso que o teclado fique ativado direto e preciso que o botão Return do campo de texto fique desativado, para que o teclado não se feche ao aperta-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de desabilitar a ação do botão de *return* é utilizar o delegate como o @Paulo respondeu. Mas, você não pode, pura e simplesmente, travar o teclado aberto em uma view. Isso vai contra os bons padrões de usabilidade e contra o documento de usabilidade da Apple.

Recomendo que você faça uma verificação de qual **UITextField** está fazendo a chamada e agir de acordo.

Por exemplo, caso seja o texto que chamou o return, mudar o foco para o numérico e, caso seja o numérico, recolher o teclado.

```obj-c
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == self.texto) {
        [self.numero becomeFirstResponder];   
    }else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Entendi... no meu caso estou com esse problema exatamente por que o teclado numérico não tem o botão de return... então para evitar a diferença, eu estava pensando em desativar o botão do teclado alfa e deixar criar a barrinha em cima dos teclados...

Comment: @DavidBatistadaSilva, a melhor solução para possibilitar a navegação em um **UITextField** numérico é, realmente, adicionar um botão sobre o teclado, através da propriedade **inputAccessoryView**. Caso precise de ajuda para isso, abra uma pergunta que posto um código de exemplo.

Comment: Cara, eu criei uma nova pergunta para o questão do botão no adicionar um botão no teclado do **UITextField**.
Segue o link [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6199/como-adicionar-botao-no-keyboard-numerico-no-ios]

Comment: Eu cheguei a ver essa pergunta. Mas, quando vi, a pergunta já tinha sido respondida. E, pelo que vi, você encontrou a resolução.

Comment: Opa cara, valeu. Queria confirmar se era essa mesmo a sua solução pra conseguir identificar a melhor! rs
Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Eu daria a mesma resposta que o Júlio deu. Inclusive, acredito que utilizar o 'inputAcessoryView' seja uma opção melhor do que inserir um botão sobre o teclado numérico. Isto porque o _AcessoryView_ é um padrão conhecido e aplicado em mercado.

Answer (score 2):

O que você pode fazer para prevenir isso é utilizar o *delegate* `textFieldShouldReturn:` do **UITextField**, assim por exemplo:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}
```

Ao menos no **iPhone**, o botão "Retorno" por si só não tem nenhuma ação automática, até que você defina uma neste mesmo *delegate*. No **iPad**, acredito que a função padrão é `[textField resignFirstResponder]` mas você pode prevenir isso também.