# Como adicionar botão no keyboard numérico no iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou desenvolvendo um app que em uma das tela há apenas dois `UITextField`, uma alfanumérico e um numérico. Ai entra meu problema, o keyboard alpha tem o botão return/next, mas o keyboard numérico não tem.

Inicialmente minha ideia seria desativar o botão return/next do keyboard alfanumérico e incluir uma pequena barra em cima dos keyboards com dois campos, um next e um previous para a navegação. Mas já me falaram por aqui que isso não não segue o padrão de usabilidade.

Tenho como incluir um botão de "Next" no espaço em branco ao lado da tecla 0 do keyboard numérico?

Comment: alguma versão do iOS especifica?

Comment: Cara, estou utilizando a ultima versão mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte biblioteca:

https://github.com/broderboy/iphone-DoneCancelNumberPadToolbar

A idéia é criar uma toolbar no topo do number pad com o botão "OK" ou "Cancelar".

Você também pode adicionar diretamente via código:

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                 nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Este código foi retirado da mesma resposta via o StackOverflow em inglês, mas funciona normalmente.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone

Comment: Opa Júlio, até ai tudo bem! rs
Mas isso não tira meu problema inicial do keyboard alfa ficar com o botão next/return e o keyboard numérico não ter...
Minha ideia era ou deixar os dois keyboards sem.... ou deixar os dois com... então acredito que no meu caso seja necessário incluir o botão next no keyboard numérico mesmo...

Comment: Julio, na mesma resposta tem esse link abaixo que é o que eu estava procurando.
So vou testar pra ver se funciona, vlws!
http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Comment: Ótimo David. :)